# How to ensure the page refreshes when on screen using React Scroll for React JS

Tags: reactjs, animation, scroll, react-hooks, gsap

I am using React Scroll to scroll to various components within my app. I am using 'gsap' for animations and would like to know if it's possible to have the page refresh (for desired component) every time I scroll to said component. The purpose is to initialise my 'gsap' animations each time I land on the component page.

I am using react hooks and so far have tried useEffect and window.location.reload() with no joy;

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-waypoint to trigger events at certain scroll position. The event is triggered on either user scrolling or automatic scrolling. You just have to place a a Waypoint component to a certain place in your page and you can trigger an event when this component will be visible. For example:

```js
const [animatedComponentVisible, setAnimatedComponentVisible] = React.useState(false);

return (

// somwhere deep in your page

  <Waypoint
    onEnter={() => setAnimatedComponentVisible(true)}
  />
  {animatedComponentVisible && <AnimatedComponent>}
)
```

Is it solve your problem?

Comment: Is it what you searched for? It could be changed to component reload as well.